# Coldfusion 10 Ignores IIS authorization rules

Tags: iis, coldfusion, authorization, coldfusion-10

I have a website for which I am trying to configure the security of certain directories.   I have added the appropriate deny and allow rules under IIS Authorization Rules.

- If a user tries to access the folder without specifying the file name in the URL, IIS kicks in and applies the rules properly.  For example, https://example.org/siteadmin/groupeditor will correctly cause IIS authorization rules to be applied.
- If the user tries to access a static file like *.jpg or *.htm, IIS will also properly apply the authorization rules.  https://example.org/siteadmin/groupeditor/mypicture.gif or https://example.org/siteadmin/groupeditor/test.htm will cause IIS authorization rules to be applied.
- If a user knows the CFM page name, they can access the page.  https://example.org/siteadmin/groupeditor/mypage.cfm will render

I have the pages "guarded" with logic in an application.cfc to check to see if the user is in an appropriate role.  However, it is bugging me to no end that this configuration isn't working properly.  The only thing that I can guess is that somehow ColdFusion's ISAPI filter is getting access to the request before IIS.  Is this correct?  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: In other words, IIS authorization is applying the way you intend for all files other than .cfm/cfc?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Comment: In my experience IIS just hands off the request to ColdFusion because it was a cfm/cfc page and doesn't do anything else with the request.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that is indeed the case.  I found an answer on another forum (http://adobe.ly/1zYvXMg) where they indicated something to the contrary, but they didn't back up their statements with a proper source (or at least any that I can find).  The fact that the rules get applied to static files and not to cfm/cfc files bears witness to the fact that IIS is handing the request off to CF's ISAPI.  It looks like the security for my sub-apps will have to rely exclusively on the code in the extended application.cfc(s).